# React typescript: How to fix Property does not exists

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my project trying to add onsubmit using react-hook-forms. Here I am facing an error

"Property 'email' does not exist on type '{ id?: string | undefined; email?: string | undefined; latitude?: string | undefined; longitude?: string | undefined; }[]'.ts(2339)"

actions.tsx

```
  const { mutate: createForm } = useCreateShareSurveyEmail();

  const onSubmit = (data: SchemaEmailShareSurvey) => {
    createForm({
      id: data?.id,
      message: data?.message,
      subject: data?.subject,
      participants: [
        {
          id: data?.participants?.id,
          email: data?.participants?.email,
          latitude: data?.participants?.latitude,
          longitude: data?.participants?.longitude,
        },
      ],
    });
  };
```

types.ts

```
export type SharesurveyEmailPayload = {
  id?:string;
  message?: string;
  subject?: string;
  participants?:{
    id?: string | any,
    email?: string | any,
    latitude?: string | any,
    longitude?: string | any
  }[];
};
```

schema.ts

```
export const schemaForShareSurveyEmail = z.object({
  id: z.string().optional(),
  subject: z.string().optional(),
  message: z.string().optional(),
  participants: z.object({
      id: z.string().optional(),
      email: z.string().optional(),
      latitude: z.string().optional(),
      longitude: z.string().optional(),
  }).array().optional(),

 
});
```

[image]

I am a beginner in react typescript, I refer to some resources to fix this problem. But it failed. Please give me some solutions to fix this problem.

[image]

Comment: `data.participants` is an **array**. Did you mean to use `data.participants[0].email`?

Comment: Yes.I want to use in that way also.